# Eclipse is reading Apache Catalina output from standard error

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Based on the color of my Eclipse console, it seems as though it's outputting standard console messages to the Standard Error buffer. Why does it do this? And, more importantly, is there a way to change this so that it works properly to make debugging simpler?

```
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 681 ms
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 14, 2013 4:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
May 14, 2013 4:44:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 14, 2013 4:44:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 14, 2013 4:44:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 396 ms
```

Comment: good question, I noticed it on last eclipse and tomcat version too.